# Cannot print from Mac Sierra to Canon 7550

Tags: macos, high-sierra, printing, airprint

A question on behalf of my Swiss neighbour

She has a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running Sierra, and a Canon 7550 printer (MG7500 series).

- WiFi router is configured on Macbook (browsing works fine).
- The printer (Canon 7550) is configured on the MacBook, with the
  correct print driver version installed and a little green circle
  showing beside it's name (suggesting the installation is good).
- The printer IP address is configured (listed) on the WiFi router.

Nevertheless, every time a print job is started, we get the message: in German: "Drucken - Der Drucker reagiert nicht" (English equivalent: "Print: The printer is not responding").

Despite a superficially correct end-to-end configuration, the Mac doesn't seem to "see" the Canon 7550.

It also fails to "see" the printer using a direct USB cable connection, and using Airprint.

Strange is that my neighbour went to a friend with her MacBook, and could print to her neighbour's Canon printer with no problem.

We've deleted and (in all but results) correctly reconfigured everything quite a few times - to no effect.

Would be grateful for a couple of further troubleshooting suggestions or tweaks.

Tks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What app are you using to print from? Have you tried different apps?  Have you gone to System Preferences and selected Printers and Scanners?  If so, what did the Printers and scanners say?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different. :) If I recall correctly, this model also has a scanner. If so, can the MBP scan okay?  Also, what happens if you start from scratch again and only try using the printer via USB (i.e. don't even configure/try Wi-Fi or AirPrint? Finally, what Canon printer did your neighbour's friend have?